# Oscillocope interleave mode and repetitive mode

Tags: oscilloscope

Could someone tell me what interleave mode and repetitive mode are in oscilloscope?

References would be good too.

Comment: That verbiage sounds specific to that model of scope. What are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a general name. It is Yokogawa DL 7200.

Answer (score 6):

I'm slightly guessing here, and I think you are using an analog scope. The average oscilloscope is single beam and can therefore only draw a single line at a time. But you have two (ore more) input channels. To be able to draw both channels two different tricks can be used, mainly depending on the selected time base. The commonly know terms are as follows:

- 'alternating' for 'repetitive' mode.
- 'chopping' for 'interleave 'and

**Alternating**

The simplest mode to show two or more traces on an oscilloscope is *alternating* mode. A full timebase sweep is made by drawing the first channel full left to full right on the screen, then the timebase is restarted and draws the second channel again full left to full right. This repeats itself indefinitely and when fast enough, it appears to the eye asif both traces are drawn at the same time.

[image]

The disadvantage of alternating mode is that it takes at least twice as long to refresh a single trace and the display will start to flicker nervously when the refreshes for a full screen drop below approximately 20ms.

**Chopping**

Some oscilloscopes will automatically switch between chopping and alternating mode, some have a manual switch. Rule of thumb is that for time base setting at 1ms/div or below you want to switch to chopping mode.

In *chopping* mode the oscilloscope switches very fast between the channel inputs, drawing an extremely short subsection of each trace. As the scope manages the beam to switch very fast between the two traces, the vertical line will not show, but input traces will.

The disadvantage for chopping mode is that when the time base setting gets lower, the screen updates faster, the chopping effect will start to show on screen.

**Digital**

Digital scopes, and especially the ones with an LCD display, don't suffer from this problem as these displays don't use a single electron beam to draw the display but an LCD panel instead. You won't find this setting on digital scopes.

Found the image in [this article](http://hobbyprojects.com/oscilloscope_tutorial/oscilloscope_vertical_controls.html) here.

Comment: I think http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/69071/8627 is the better answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Repetitive mode**

This mode is used when the input signal is changing faster than the analog to digital converter can do its conversion. The mechanism behind this mode is that the signal measured is repeating itself. So what happens is that the signal is measured for example at t=0, t=10, t=20, t=30, t=40, ...

To increase the picture quality/resolution, after the first full timebase sweep subsequent measurements are taken: t=1, t=11, t=21, t=31, t=41, ...

And again t=2, t=12, t=22, t=32, t=42, ...

You get the picture. A full image is built over time. This mode only works when the input signal is repetitive.

Advantage of this mode is the much higher frequency you can capture, disadantage is a higher probability to miss glitches.

[image]

For interleave mode refer to [@ThePhoton](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/69141/8627)'s anwer.

Comment: See the manual here (now that OP has told us what model): http://energy.ece.illinois.edu/equipment/dl7100.pdf. What you call "interleave mode", they call "repetitive mode." Their "interleave mode" is something else entirely.

Comment: @jippie, is the interleave mode you described the same as the one Photon describes? Also, Could you elaborate the repetitive mode more? Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer to be in line with the manual @ThePhoton refers to and removed the part that was apparently wrong.

Comment: Repetitive mode is a way to fake interleaving by exploiting the fact that the input signal is ... repetitive. They generally accomplish the same thing, but repetitive mode can only work when the input is a repeating wave, so the sampling interval can be dithered across the waveform.

Answer (score 4):

I found the manual for your scope [here](http://energy.ece.illinois.edu/equipment/dl7100.pdf).

Interleave mode and Repetitive mode are separate/orthogonal functions. You can have one or both of these functions on or neither of them.

Interleave mode "doubles the amount of memory per channel, while cutting the number of
channels in half." Essentially it disables channels 2 and 4, and makes their memory space available for storing data captured on channels 1 and 3. It allows storing and manipulating longer data records on channels 1 and 3.

Repetitive mode is described by @jippie in his answer --- a way to sample a repetitive signal with more resolution, without increasing how often the ADCs are actually triggered.

Comment: Interleave mode often also doubles the sample-per-second rate, by using the ADCs for channel 1 and 2 180° out of phase. In this case, for this scope, the maximum sample rate is 500 MSps with interleave off, and 1 GSps with it on.